# JsonConverter is not used on certain types of containers

Tags: json.net, deserialization, converters

I have a class that inherits from JsonConverter:
`JsonDataBagCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : IDataBag`

I have a class Company that implements IDataBag

When I deserialize a *single property* of Company JsonDataBagCreationConverter has its ReadJson method invoked as I expect.
When I deserialize an *array* of Company, JsonDataBagCreationConverter has its ReadJson method invoked as I expect.
It also works for *generic* lists of Company.

But for certain containers of Company json.net will not recognize that the contents of the list is of type Company. So JsonDataBagCreationConverter is not used when I deserialize.

ie containers of type
    System.Collections.DictionaryEntry, 
    System.Collections.ArrayList, 
    System.Collections.Hashtable,
    System.Collections.SortedList
that stores Company objects.

I know that these containers are non-generic.
Is it possible to make the (de-)serializer look at the *contents* of these containers and use the JsonDataBagCreationConverter when the contents is Idatabag (ie a company)?

Best regards

Jan

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `where T : IDataBag` from the converter and override  `CanConvert` and write your logic to check your type there and accordly return true or false.